# Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported`

Tags: android, android-studio

Please help me with this error getting in my project while trying to run at mobile via android studio.

Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

Comment: Have you tried what is suggested in the error message?

Comment: there is nothing suggested

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 14):

Add this to your manifest to the activity tag in the error message:

```
android:exported="true"
```

This happens when your activity can be started by another application. For example image viewer can be started by file manager when clicking an image. The image viewer app is "exported".

It's also always required if you are using the following code necessary for dynamic links:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Example:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
       
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: this should be added inside Activity tag.

Comment: Still getting the same message after adding the exported properties in manifest in all activities that will be opened by other apps.

Comment: The error says the activity tag that required the attribute.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I never would've found that [android:exported="true"] if you hadn't explained it. The error in AndroidStudio even takes you to that place, but I didn't understand it.  Thanks for the help. Worked and resolved the issue.

Answer (score 7):

I found this [solution!!](https://programmerah.com/solved-manifest-merger-failed-apps-targeting-android-12-and-higher-are-required-to-specify-an-explicit-33433/).

So you have to add the `android:exported="true"` into the activity tag in the manifest (not in the application).

```
<application
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/my_backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".yourActivity" android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".otherActivity" android:exported="true"/>

    </application>
```

To see more information about the exported property, see [App manifest file activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported)

:)

Answer (score 3):

if you are using flutter ,may some deprecated lib in your ap is causing this ..
for me: upgrading `flutter_local_notifications` to the latest version (now is 9.3.2) solved this error..

Comment: That's exactly what happened with me. Even though the error specifically pointed at my own Mainfest.xml file (which had the expected line), updating flutter_local_notifications library did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If you have any activity, service, receiver, or provider that does not have **exported** set in your manifest file then add whenever it needed like,

```js
android:exported="false or true"
```

Answer (score 2):

You had to figure out the component missing the Android exported tag.
You should downgrade your SDK version and check the final merged manifest file for the components missing the exported tag but has IntentFilter.

The step-by-step instructions is provided in  [this link](https://tedblob.com/android-12-safer-component-exporting/#debug-android-exported).

Answer (score 1):

Add android:exported="true" into the Manifest file inside of the application activity

```
<application
    <activity
        android:exported="true"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NoteKeeper.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Already added... The problem is not resolved

Answer (score 1):

**This is for the projects using Bootsplash.**
My project used **Bootsplash** and I solved it by adding `android:exported="true"` also to the activity of Bootsplash in the AndroidManifest file.

```
<application
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    android:exported="true"                   // <----ADD THIS
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    
  </activity>
   <activity
    android:name="com.zoontek.rnbootsplash.RNBootSplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/BootTheme"
    android:exported="true"                    // <----ADD THIS
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just add local notification package, and that error appear try to make your

> android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
> to look like

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.environmental">
   <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:label="environmental"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
   

 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true"
       
        >
      

  <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            
        </activity>
       

        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

            <!-- malicer -->
      <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ActionBroadcastReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- malicer -->
    </application>
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
    <!-- malicer -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <!-- malicer -->
</manifest>
```

add those line which are absent in your file, then run

> flutter clean and then flutter build

NOTE: This is based much for problem caused by **flutter_local_notification** package

am using ***flutter_local_notifications: ^8.2.0***

Answer (score 0):

I had to add
**android:exported="true"**

In all the tags where **intent-filter** was present
For me they were

receiver
service
activity

I faced this issue while upgrading my React Native app to v12.
as I was facing a crash upon receiving the notification.